# C++: Constructor troubles

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to teach myself C++, and I'm going through a basic exercise about constructors.  I have one program that is behaving unexpectedly:

Fraction.h:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H

using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
private:
    int num;
    int denom;
    static int gcd(int a, int b);
    void reduce();
public:
    Fraction(int n=0, int d=1);
    Fraction(Fraction& f);
    ~Fraction();

    Fraction& operator=(const Fraction& f);

    friend Fraction operator+(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Fraction& f);
};

#endif // FRACTION_H
```

Fraction.cpp (some implementations omitted):

```
#include "../include/Fraction.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Fraction::gcd(int a, int b) {
    // implementation omitted
}

void Fraction::reduce() {
    // implementation omitted
    // this just reduces fractions to lowest terms, like 3/6 to 1/2
}

Fraction::Fraction(int n, int d) {
    cout << "new fraction, n=" << n << ", d=" << d << endl;
    assert(d != 0);
    if (d < 0) {
        num = -n;
        denom = -d;
    } else {
        num = n;
        denom = d;
    }
    reduce();
}

Fraction::Fraction(Fraction& f) {
    cout << "copy fraction " << f << " at " << &f << endl;
    num = f.num;
    denom = f.denom;
}

Fraction::~Fraction() {
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator=(const Fraction& f) {
    cout << "assign fraction to " << f << " at " << &f << endl;
    if (this == &f)
        return *this;
    num = f.num;
    denom = f.denom;
    return *this;
}

Fraction operator+(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2) {
    cout << "adding " << f1 << " and " << f2 << endl;
    return Fraction(f1.num * f2.denom + f2.num * f1.denom,
                    f1.denom * f2.denom);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Fraction& f) {
    out << f.num << "/" << f.denom;
    return out;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "include/Fraction.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Fraction f1(1, 3);
    Fraction f2(1, 2);
    cout << f1 << endl;
    cout << f2 << endl;
    cout << (f1 + f2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the first two print statements output `1/3` and `1/2` as expected, but the third one prints `0/1` instead of `5/6`.  From the debugging statements I have, I create 5/6 through the `Fraction(int, int)` constructor, but for some reason it then gets called with 0/1.  When I remove the copy constructor, the code prints out `5/6`.  What's going on here, and how can I fix it without removing the copy constructor?

Comment: Too much of the code responsible for the problem is missing. Can you either post the rest of the code or create a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hey just out of curiosity - which compiler were you using for this?  I'm interested in seeing how it allowed the missing `const` in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The signature for your copy constructor should be

```
Fraction(const Fraction&);
```

*not*

```
Fraction(Fraction&);
```

When you do `return Fraction(...);`, the compiler has to call `Fraction(const Fraction&)` because the fraction being returned is a temporary, but since you don't define it, your compiler makes something weird happen. Your compiler is behaving weirdly and allowing you to use the default constructor somehow, when it should kick out an error. Compiling your code as-is on gcc doesn't work, you'll have to make the modification I mentioned and that should fix it.

Also, the fact that your compiler isn't using RVO on that function hints that you are using a very old and/or sucky compiler.

Comment: Hi @user1320895, I see you are new to StackOverflow.  Since you are sure this is the correct answer, make sure you press the "accept" check mark on this answer, that is the etiquette around here.  (I'm allowed to be the guy who reminds you since I didn't post the actual answer :-) ).

Comment: @user1320895:  you did it, awesome!  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Is that the answer? I don't see that it explains why the OP is getting the result he got. (I still don't see why that is, personally.)

Comment: I tried the code myself.  On my machine, the original code would not even compile with the `const` missing from the declaration of the copy constructor.  Once I added the `const`, the code compiled and produced the correct result.  The OP must have been using a compiler that allowed for the missing `const`.  I can only speculate on which constructor implementation his code was calling.  Anyway, it was not possible for me to duplicate the problem since my compiler could not compile the original code, but I believe the OP when he said that those were the results that his compiler produced.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz tl;dr his compiler has a bug and is accepting an ill-formed program. Probably an old version of visual studio. Or maybe the current version of visual studio.

Comment: I still don't see the answer in there. How is the program ill-formed? What in the standard does it violate?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I haven't the time to find the place in the standard (that would take a while), but if you're that interested, you can try compiling it yourself (the original code) and see that it errors. It's because there is no function it should be able to call. `Function(Function&)` should not (and is not, even on the OP's machine) be called because you can't bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary. If you leave out `Function(const Function&)`, the only thing that could be called is `Function(Function)`, which the OP's compiler is magically generating, and somehow messing up...

Comment: by making it use the default constructor somewhere in the process. Don't ask me why, the compiler is broken or something. I have only a little proof of all of this, but I think it's a very good guess and I don't really have the time or will to look into it further since the OP's problem is solved. If you decide to, please report back and let us all know what you find.

Comment: I believe the problem is that he has a copy constructor, but it can't be used in this case because that would require binding a non-const reference to a temporary. The program is ill-formed because it has a copy constructor and that copy constructor is not suitable. (It would be fine if it had no copy constructor or if it had a suitable copy constructor.)

Comment: I asked the OP in the original thread to tell us which compiler he used. It'll be interesting to find out.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that's what I said, isn't it? I must have really poor explanation skills :)

Comment: @sparc_spread yes, then I'll have another compiler to add to my "never use" list

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Maybe I just misunderstood you, but what you did was tell him a change that would fix his code and speculated about a compiler bug that might be causing his problem. You never explained what was wrong with his code or how it violated the standard. (A copy constructor that takes a const reference is not only perfectly legal in C++, but automatically created under some circumstances. So the answer is not "copy constructors should always take const references".)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I meant they _should_, not _have to_, because a copy constructor that takes a non-`const` reference is more restricted than one that takes a `const` one. I think I did tell him what was wrong with the line `When you do return Fraction(...);, the compiler has to call Fraction(const Fraction&) because the fraction being returned is a temporary, but since you don't define it, your compiler makes something weird happen. Your compiler is behaving weirdly and allowing you to use the default constructor somehow, when it should kick out an error.` Which is basically what you said...

Comment: without introducing some perhaps unfamiliar terms ("your code violates the standard..." etc). Also w.r.t. copy ctors, I never said and never do say _always_.

Comment: Except the compiler doesn't have to do call `Fraction(const Fraction&)` because it can elide it. And even if it did have to call it, one could easily think the compiler would be permitted to create an implicit one. As I read his question, this was what he was asking. What was wrong with his code? Now how could he fix it, but what was wrong with it. And to answer that, you need to explain that an explicit copy constructor overrides any implicit one, even in contexts in which it cannot be invoked. Also, part of the answer is that any construct that *requires* elision is illegal.